# find word occurrences in matrix matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a big matrix which cells represent the number of occurrences of a word (row) in a text document (column).

```
counts = rand(567840,799); % 567840 words,799 text documents
```

Without executing a loop I need to:

1) extract the indeces of the words that occurr in at least the 90% of the text documents

2) extract the indeces of the words that occour max 2 times in all the collection of documents.

for the point 2 I would do

```
idx_2 = find(sum(counts,2)<=2);
```

I am struggling with point 1...
Can you help me?

Comment: It would be good if you posted some samples of your matrix.

Comment: Hi! I already converted my text file in a matrix of counts. rows are words and columns are documents. the value in the cells(i,j) are the number of occurrences of the word i in the document j.

Comment: Yes, but it would useful for others who are trying to help/ reading this post in the future to know what your matrix looks like.

Comment: For point 1: `mean(counts > 0, 2) >= 0.9` ? This finds words that appear _at least once_ in at least 90% of the documents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1 you can do

```
idx1 = find(mean(counts > 0, 2) >= 0.9);
```

and for 2 as you said

```
idx2 = find(sum(counts, 2) <= 2);
```

*Edit* - I see Luis Mendo already mentioned this in the comments so I have marked this community wiki.